# Using tests.py file with apps in a root directory

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I have a small project with all the apps inside a root directory named apps.

Everything works fine, but now I tried to add some tests in the tests.py

```
class CursoModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_two_identical_slugs(self):
        curso1 = Curso(
            nombre='Curso 1', precio=10, descripcion_breve='Hola', 
            slug='prueba', profesor=create_profesor()
        )

    with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
        Curso(
            nombre='Curso 2', precio=20, descripcion_breve='Otro curso',
            slug='prueba', profesor=create_profesor()
        )
```

And when I run python manage.py test apps I get this error

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: curso.tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: curso.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path        
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name  
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Apps creadas\cocina-salud\CocinaSalud\apps\curso\tests.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .models import Curso
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Apps creadas\cocina-salud\CocinaSalud\apps\curso\models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Curso(BaseModel):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Apps creadas\cocina-salud\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 132, in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class curso.models.Curso doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

When I define an app_label in the Meta class this way

```
class Curso(BaseModel):
    # fields...
    
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'apps.curso'
```

I receive this other error

```
Found 1 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: curso.tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: curso.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path        
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name  
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Apps creadas\cocina-salud\CocinaSalud\apps\curso\tests.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .models import Curso
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Apps creadas\cocina-salud\CocinaSalud\apps\curso\models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Curso(BaseModel):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Apps creadas\cocina-salud\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 364, in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Apps creadas\cocina-salud\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 234, in register_model
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'curso' models in application 'apps.curso': <class 'apps.curso.models.Curso'> and <class 'curso.models.Curso'>.


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

This is my apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CursoConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'apps.curso'
```

And I have the apps declared in INSTALLED_APPS in the way 'apps.curso'.

If you need more information about the project structure please let me know